# php read csv and limit records to execute

Tags: php, api, csv

I am using an api and before I submit the data for the api to process it, I need to format the data, 
I have the data in csv file in 5 columns
now, I want to open and read the csv file join the fields with comma between each column except the last column. I am almost done with parsing the csv by using [parsecsv](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/), got the data now, then added "," after each field's value but now I have one comma at the end which I need to remove, so now I am trying to use substr to just remove the last one but it's not working right. It removes all the comma..can you please take a look?

```
foreach ($csv->data as $key => $row){
  foreach ($row as $value) {
     $output =  "$value, ";
      //echo $output;
     $final = substr($output, 0, -2);
    echo $final."\n";
    }
}
```

I have other question, I have some idea but not sure if this will work. This api can accept only 100 records at a time, so i need to run the script several times to finish the process. How this can be done? I am thinking that I should first get the count of rows from csv and then inside a loop, execute it for 100 and then continue..but to continue, should I pause after 100 and then continue? please advise me..it would be great if some example can be seen and  I can go from there..

thanks

Comment: Your code to build it is wrong, as you're assigning to $output on each iteration (rather than appending to it). Have a look at using fputcsv instead though. You can also open a temporary file in memory by opening a file called `php://temp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$final .= substr($output, 0, -2);
```

Comment: sure, will try this..any idea for the second part? each time the number of records is different, so now it can be 5000 records so I need to call to the api for 50 times...next day it can be 6000 records..so how can i do this call?

Comment: That's weird, perhaps you should write your own api. For a start, this should make an array of all the elements in the csv string: $array = explode(',', $csvstring);  If you want a more complex solution, check the related questions on the right.